# Состояния Edit Text, телефонная маска в edittext

Tags: android, android-edittext

Нужно сделать телефонную маску для `EditText`. Сделал вот так: `etRegistrationPhone.setOnFocusChangeListener(this);`

```
@Override
public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.etRegistrationPhone:
            etRegistrationPhone.setText(R.string.country_phone_code);
            break;
    }
}
```

Когда я нажимаю на него, всё работает, и курсор становится после +380
а когда я перехожу на этот `EditText` с верхнего, нажимая на клавиатуре "далее" - курсор моргает перед нужным мне кодом.

В чем разница между этими действиями? Как сделать так, чтобы курсор устанавливался после моего кода, если я перехожу на него с верхнего `EditText` нажимая кнопку "далее"?

Comment: Попробуйте https://github.com/RedMadRobot/input-mask-android

Comment: Или это: https://github.com/TinkoffCreditSystems/decoro

Comment: @v.andrikeev спасибо. воспользовался Вашим советом!

Answer (score 0):

> В чем разница между этими действиями?

Разница в том, что когда вы нажимаете на поле, то курсор ставится в то место, куда вы нажали, то есть в конец. Если вы нажмёте на самое начало поля, то курсор встанет туда.

> Как сделать так, чтобы курсор устанавливался после моего кода, если я
>   перехожу на него с верхнего `EditText` нажимая кнопку "далее"?

После получения фокуса и установки текста нужно вручную установить позицию курсора на конец строки:

```
etRegistrationPhone.setText(R.string.country_phone_code);
etRegistrationPhone.setSelection(etRegistrationPhone.getText().length());
```